# Turning off console output?

Tags: debian, console, arm, output

I have a Debian on beaglebone without an X server and I need to get rid of any console output to the framebuffer device.

I was trying few things I found, like `console=null` or kernel argument `vga=0`, but without luck.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a vga in your BeagleBone.

In my Lamobo R1 (ARM like the BB) I am passing to the kernel the parameters

```
sunxi_ve_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_g2d_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_fb_mem_reserve=0 console=ttyS1,115200n8
```

and took out the ones:

```
console=tty1 disp.screen0_output_mode=1920x1080p60
```

Why this parameters:

sunxi_ve_mem_reserve=0

> This eliminates the reserved memory for the video acceleration engine,
>   saving 80MB.

sunxi_g2d_mem_reserve=0

> This eliminates the reserved memory for the 2D acceleration engine.

sunxi_fb_mem_reserve=0

> This sets the amount of total reserved memory for the framebuffer to
>   0.

console=ttyS1,115200n8

- Using the console via a PL2303HX USB to UART TTL cable

console=tty1

- Took it out because the terminal output was using the framebuffer.

Since you are not interested in video output, you might also be interested in a BeagleBone Green, a BeagleBone without a HDMI connector.

https://beagleboard.org/green